# How to get status of a running Process in Scala

Tags: scala

Earlier I runned `val pb = Process("""java -version""")` and it gave me an exitValue of `0` as expected but code below runs process without exiting or blocking, so how can I get exitValue, my requirement actually is how to get status of a process that runs in background without stopping.

```
object Sample extends App {

  import scala.sys.process.Process

  val pb = Process("""java -jar common-api_2.11-1.3-one-jar.jar""")

  val x = pb.run

  print( "Exit value :" + x.exitValue )
}
```

Comment: As the process does not exit, it makes sense that there is no exit code, that is you will get the exit code when the process finishes at some point as `exitValue` blocks until the process exits. What kind of status other than running do you want to get?

Comment: I mean is it possible to get some status  from the process that is running, so that I will print something like its running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the std output of a running process by passing a `ProcesLogger` to the run method:

e.g.

```
val logger = ProcessLogger((msg: String) ⇒ println(msg))
val x = pb.run(logger)
```

will print all output to the System.out. -but you can pass a function that would parse and evaluate the output of the process to extract some kind of state meaningful to your application. You can also pass a different function for statndard and error output. Have a look at `ProcessLogger.apply` variants.